# appendChildする際、親要素に[0]を付与するのはどんな時？ getElementsByClassNameでは必須？

Tags: javascript, dom

**appendChildする際、親要素に[0]を付与する条件がよく分かりません**

---

**getElementById**
・[0]不要？

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
document.getElementById('target').appendChild(p);
```

---

**getElementsByClassName**
・[0]必要？

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
document.getElementsByClassName('target')[0].appendChild(p);
```

---

**document.属性**
・[0]不要？
・もしくは属性に因る？

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

---

**あるいは取得結果数によるのでしょうか？**
・getElementsByClassNameでも、取得結果が1件なら、[0]不要？

Comment: get**Element**ById / create**Element** など -> `Element` は単数形ですから、戻り値はあの要素あるいは null です。get**Elements**ByClassName / get**Elements**ByTagName など -> `Elements` は複数形ですから、戻り値は要素の配列です。

Comment: コメントありがとうございました。戻り値に注目すれば良いんですね。太字していただいているようにメソッド名自体に「Element」「Elements」と明記されていますね。参考になりました

Comment: @neuront  正確には配列ではありません。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ご指摘ありがとうございます。確かに配列ではなく、`NodeList`という型です。要素や `.length` でサイズを取得できますが、`push`や `concat` など配列らしい操作は通用しません。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

ＩＤはそのページで唯一でなければならないので、（もしあれば）結果は１つのエレメントであり[0]は不要です。

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

結果はノードリスト(配列の様に扱える)であり、
例え結果が１つのエレメントであっても[0]が必要です（値が１つの配列と同じ意味）。

`document.body` は、
`body`要素を意味する(例えば`id="foo"`をbody要素に付ければ`document.body === document.getElementById("foo")`は`true`になる）ただ一つのエレメントですので不要です。

[html 要素](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html) から引用

> 許可された内容    ひとつの `<head>` 要素と、それに続くひとつの `<body>` 要素。

[body 要素](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body) から引用

> `<body>` 要素は、HTML 文書のコンテンツを示す要素です。`<body>` 要素は文書中に一つだけ配置できます。

要するに、ノード検索・指定する場合にノードリスト（ノード集合）が返るような場合にインデクスによるアクセスが必要で、ノードリストにならない一つのノードの場合必要無いということですね。

Comment: メソッドの戻り値が「1つの要素」or「ノードリスト」、の違いですね。リンク提示＆引用ありがとうございました。これまで何となくコピペしていたのですが、ようやく理解できました